# forum layout suddenly changed

Tags: support, user-interface

Why has suddenly my maths stack exchange changed to this layout? It didn't use to look like this and I don't think I changed a setting. help?

[image: what the hell has happened?]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the mobile site. Go to the bottom and click on "full site".

Comment: I just realised. I feel so ashamed asking it now... I don't even know what I have clicked...

Comment: No worries; the only reason I could answer so quickly is that I've had a similar problem before, and so was able to guess this might be the problem! :)

Comment: What "bottom" and where is that "full site" thing, please?

Comment: @Don: (In my view) there is a menu after the list of questions. On the mobile site, this appears at the end of the webpage, and contains a "full site" link. On the full site, the menu has a "mobile" link, and is followed by the list of stackexchange sites.

Comment: Thanks Hurkyl. For some reason some 5-6 hour ago I couldn't write comments, questions , answers. The site won't let me. I tried to click on the "add comment" thing and it won't open. Very odd. Things seem to be fine now.